# display grid of data in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, columns, freeipa

would like to get an opinion on how best to do this in bash, thank you

for x number of servers, each has it's own list of replication agreements and their status.. it's easy to run a few commands and get this data, ex;

get servers, output;

```
dc1-server1 dc1-server2 dc2-server1 dc2-server2 dc3...
```

for dc1-server1, get agreements, output;

```
dc2-server1
dc3-server1
dc4-server1
```

for dc1-server1, get agreement status codes, output;

```
0
0
18
```

so output would be several columns based on the 'get servers' list with each 'replica: status' under each server, for that server

this may get munged, but something like;

```
dc1-server1      dc1-server2      dc2-server1
dc2-server1: 0   dc2-server2: 0   dc1-server1: 0  ...
dc3-server1: 0   dc3-server2: 18  dc3-server1: 13 ...
dc4-server1: 18  dc4-server2: 0   dc4-server1: 0  ...
```

something vaguely like this (tho this doesn't work);

```
#!/bin/bash

. ~/.ldap-config
DOMAIN=$(domainname)
ROWSTOT=0

for SERVER in $MASTER $REPLICAS ; do
   ${SERVER}REPLICAS=$(ipa-replica-manage -p $(cat ~/.dsp) list -v $SERVER.$DOMAIN | grep ': replica' | sed 's/: replica//')
   ROWS=$(echo "${SERVER}REPLICAS" | wc -l)
   [ "$ROWS" -gt "$ROWSTOT" ] && ROWSTOT=$ROWS
   ${SERVER}STATUS=$(ipa-replica-manage -p $(cat ~/.dsp) list -v $SERVER.$DOMAIN | grep 'status: Error (' | sed -e 's/.*status: Error (//' -e 's/).*//')
done

for (( C=1; C<=$ROWSTOT; C++ )) ; do
   for SERVER in $MASTER $REPLICAS ; do
      #echo -n "${SERVER}REPLICAS[$C]: ${SERVER}STATUS[$C]"
      printf "%-28s" "${SERVER}REPLICAS[$C]: ${SERVER}STATUS[$C]"
   done
   echo
done
```

example output from ipa-replica-manage;

```
# ipa-replica-manage -p $(cat ~/.dsp) list -v $(hostname)
dc1-server2.domain: replica
  last update status: Error (0) Replica acquired successfully: Incremental update succeeded
  last update ended: 2021-04-08 12:13:05+00:00
dc4-server2.domain: replica
  last update status: Error (0) Replica acquired successfully: Incremental update succeeded
  last update ended: 2021-04-08 12:13:05+00:00
dc3-server1.domain: replica
  last update status: Error (0) Replica acquired successfully: Incremental update succeeded
  last update ended: 2021-04-08 12:13:05+00:00
dc2-server1.domain: replica
  last update status: Error (0) Replica acquired successfully: Incremental update succeeded
  last update ended: 2021-04-08 12:13:05+00:00
```

.ldap-config has local env/cluster settings (there are several clusters w/different server names/quantities), but the only lines used here are, ex;

```
MASTER=dc1-server1
REPLICAS="dc1-server2 dc2-server1 dc2-server2 dc3...  "
```

Comment: Please add more details on how you receive the data. Are these command outputs? Are they input files?

Comment: the commands are a bit specific to the env.. for the servers list (get servers), these are in a source'd config file, which has different names/quantity depending on the env/cluster, ex; SERVERS="dc1-server1 dc2-server2 ..."

Comment: Then for each server, parse a (ipa) command to get the replication agreements server names (get agreements) and also parse the command to get replication status for those servers (get agreement status codes). 

Data all comes from; 'ipa-replica-manage list -v $SERVER'

Comment: Issue really, the data comes in as various columns to be assigned to vars during the data collection phase, but then has to be printed onscreen a row at a time for all the various servers.. kind of in a grid format.

Comment: Please take our short [tour] to learn how this site is supposed to work. Relevant information should be in the question body, not in comments. Now you should [edit] the question, put the new information there, finally delete the comments. Welcome to the site.

Comment: Could you add a typical output of `ipa-replica-manage -p $(cat ~/.dsp) list -v $SERVER.$DOMAIN`? I strongly suggest getting 'replica' and 'error status' from ONE grep command, so the values are on two consecutive lines.

Comment: # ipa-replica-manage -p $(cat ~/.dsp) list -v $(hostname) | grep -E ': replica|status: Error \(' | sed -e 's/ replica//' -e 's/.*status: Error (//' -e 's/).*//'
`dc2-server1.domain:
0
dc3-server1.domain:
18
dc1-server2.domain:
0`

Comment: I can massage various bits of the data, but/tho the question/issue really is still the same; how to print columnar data a row at a time.. part of this personally/mentally, is wrapping my brain around the variable mgmt piece during data collection.. once I have the data, I think I can manage the output, but, I was also looking for an opinion how others would go about this, mostly to try and learn something new